# Chrome Extension: Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Here is the full error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-ZSVdcA7W5dY1JWnjrNopJicPvesY+6qqEEAMYoij14A='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

A bit about the extension:

Here is the popup.html:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src='jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="employee">
    <option value="john-cleaf">John Cleaf</option>
    <option value="sarah-walker">Sarah Walker</option>
    <option value="steven-benedict">John Cleaf</option>
</select>
<button id="search-employee">Lookup</button>
<script src='popup.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the popup JS file I simply have:

```
$('#search-employee').on('click', function() {

var employee = $('#employee').val();

if (employee == "john-cleaf") {
    $('body').html('John has been with the company for over 7 years');
}

});
```

When I click the extension icon in the toolbar, the first page pops up. I can select the name, and then when I press lookup it works and loads the information by changing the html.

However, it is after that has happened that I seem to be having the trouble. The error then shows up on the new loaded content.

I need to be able to add another button in the section for the employee so I do need js to be allowed.

so 2 questions:

1) Why is the javascript allowed to work and load first time?
2) How can I make it work both times?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Ever figure this out?